# Robot framework-IE browser supporrt

Tags: robotframework

I have been trying to run the test cases against I.E browser

The following is my code

```
*** settings ***

Library     Selenium2Library
Library     ExcelLibrary

*** variables ***

${URL_LOCATIONS}        www.google.com(for example) 
${BROWSER_TYPE}         ie
${DELAY_TIME}           1

*** keywords ***
Open Browser 

     Open Browser   ${URL_LOCATIONS} ${BROWSER_TYPE}
```

and running the script using the following command 
**pybot --variable BROWSER:ie Main.txt**

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `${BROWSER_TYPE}` from the command line, you must use that name with the `--variable` argument:

```
pybot --variable BROWSER_TYPE:ie Main.txt
```